# What does 'developer credentials' exactly mean in the Amazon Cognito docs

Tags: amazon-cognito

What is the definition of 'developer credentials' shown in the amazon cognito docs as per the screenshot and url below.

url is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateGroup.html

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you want to use aws services like Cognito, DynamoDb or Ec2 using aws-sdk, the developer who will be creating that program needs to provide the aws-console parameters like, IAM_role_ARN, PoolId, aws_account_id using which aws identifies the account of which the respective service has to be accessed.

More on the following link:

[AWS Account Identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html)

[access key best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html)

Comment: Does this mean that a Lambda Function cannot run this? is it only runnable on a local machine with develop credentials in `./aws`?

Comment: @måns-dahlström seems like lambda function will still work without mentioning any developer credentials in it.